# What's the C# equivalent of Java's Class<X> type?

Tags: c#, generics

In Java, it's convenient for Class to have the generic parameter, X.  But C#'s Type class doesn't have this.

So in C#, how does one do the equivalent of the following Java code?:

```
public <X> X methodThatReturns(Class<X> clazz) { ... }
```

There doesn't seem to be a way in C# to connect that return values, and the passed Type.

**Clarification**
Several answers are suggesting the method parameter isn't necessary, because the method could simply be defined as `methodThatReturns<X>()`.

But if you *do* have some unknown Type variable, `t`, there's basically no way to call such a generic method so that it will return an object of Type `t`?

In Java, you're free to pass around `Class<X>` variables without losing the type information, but it seems that in C# if you pass around the equivalent `Type` variables, you can run into limitations, because you can't use them when you need to call generic methods.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I'm not much of a C# programmer, but I think this idiom is a lot less common in C# because C# does not have type erasure. Generic type information is retained, not lost, at runtime.

Comment: Dont think there is one.

Comment: Note to @slattery: Generics were added starting in .NET 2.0 / C# 2 / Visual Studio 2005. If you are using .NET 1.1 / C# 1.2 / Visual Studio 2002/2003, you're out of luck.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public X methodThatReturns<X>(Class<X> clazz) { ... }
```

Also keep in mind that **in C# there is no type erasure** so you can do things like `typeof(T)` without worries in case Class is meant to be the java "Class" object rather than a "some class" placeholder:

```
public X methodThatReturns<X>(X value)
{
    Type x = typeof(X); // that's fine
    if (value is SomeType) { } // that's fine too    
    return (X)someObject; // I think you get the point
}
```

Edit:

Again, since the generic type information is not lost after compilation you don't need to pass in the type explicitly:

```
public X methodThatReturns<X>()
{
    Type xType = typeof(X); // Type is to C#/.Net what Class<X> is to Java.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but I'm looking for your method to take a "Type" of X as a parameter, rather than an instance of X... something like the Type<X>.

Comment: No way to take it as a parameter, but in C# you don't need to as you can do that inside the method even if it doesn't have a parameter: `Type x = typeof(X)`. Type is the equivalent of Class in C#.

Comment: This is very unfortunate. To not have a way to express a dynamic return type via the passed in type and get compiler type checking is very limiting for certain cases.

Answer (score 3):

In C# it would be

```
public X methodThatReturns<X>() { ... }
```

and you can get type of X using `typeof(X)` instead of using the parameter `clazz`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% up on Java generics... Are you trying to declare a method that returns the same type as it was passed?

```
public T MethodThatReturns<T>(T input) { ... }
```

This method will be generic on any type, and return the same type it was passed. You can call this using:

```
AnyTypeAtAll foo = new AnyTypeAtAll();
AnyTypeAtAll bar = MethodThatReturns(foo);
```

Note that there's no `<AnyTypeAtAll>` on the call to MethodThatReturns, the compiler can figure it out given the parameter you passed. However, note that it's the compiler doing that, not runtime, so it'll only use the type of variable foo, not the type of object that foo points to.

---

On the other hand, if that's Java syntax for a method that takes no 'real' parameters, then simply:

```
public T MethodThatReturns<T>()
{
    Type clazz = typeof(T);
    ....
}
```

Within this method, you can treat T the same as you would any other class, and it will refer specifically to the type that the method was called with, not to `object` or anything like that. You may want to put `where T : class` to allow comparison to null in that method (which does prevent you from using `int` as the generic type), or `where T : new()` to restrict the generic type to have a default constructor, so you can do `T foo = new T();`

Answer (score 1):

I'm familiar with both Java and .NET generics and I use the `Class<X>` construct like that a lot in my Java projects. One of my favorite uses is to deal with non-generic collections in Java which are returned from outside code like Hibernate (I think that the latest version of Hibernate might support generics, though I'm not certain of that. We are using a rather old version of it since it is a long running project that has too much code that would have to be updated if we ever changed it.) The function works like this:

```
public <X> List<X> TypedList(List<?> lst, Class<X> cls) {
    return (List<X>) lst;
}
```

It's all very simple and the important thing is I don't have to create a dummy object to pass to the function, I just call it as:

```
List<MyObject> myLst = TypedList(lst, MyObject.class);
```

Another important thing to note is that the cls parameter isn't used at all. It's only means of giving a concrete type for X.

The way that you do this same thing is a little bit different in C#. You might think that the same function would look something like this:

```
public List<X> TypedList<X>(IList lst)
{
    return (List<X>) lst;
}
```

*But you would be dead wrong.*

The problem is that Java uses a trick called *Type Erasure*, which basically means that when the code is actually compiled, ALL generic parameters are removed from the code. So in the world of the Java Virtual Machine, there is no such thing as a `List<X>` or any other generics, they are all simple `List` and other non-generic types. This means that the generics are only there to help you code and are not enforced at runtime.

In C#, however, there is no type erasure and generics **are** enforced at runtime. This means that the following would generate a runtime exception when used with the above function:

```
List<object> lstObj = TypedList<object>(new List<string>());
```

The reason is that `List<string>` and `List<object>` are considered two completely different classes. You can't even do `List<object> lstObj = (List<object>) new List<string>();` without getting a compiler error. *This means the function cannot return the same object that was passed to it.* We **must** create a new object of the correct type and return that one. The most basic form of this would look like the following:

```
public List<X> TypedList<X>(IList lst)
{
    List<X> lstOut = new List<X>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lst.Count; i++)
    {
        if (lst[i] is X) lstOut.Add((X) lst[i]);
    }
    return lstOut;
}
```

That's rather boring and boilerplate code, but it works. For something much shorter and cleaner, LINQ is here to save the day. Check out the following:

```
public List<X> TypedList<X>(IList lst)
{
    return lst.OfType<X>().ToList();
}
```

`OfType<X>()` grabs all items in lst that are of the type X (or descendants) and skips over any that aren't. `ToList()` then builds a new `List<X>` containing all the members passed to it from `OfType<X>()`. Another advantage to this method is that we can actually change the lst parameter from being an `IList` to `IEnumberable`, which is implemented by all collection types.

One other thing to point out about this though is that it doesn't do any conversion of types, only type checking. So that means that if you wanted to take a `List<long>` and convert it to a `List<int>` or a `List<string>`, you would need to do something else. With LINQ, this would still be very simple:

```
List<long> lstLng = new List<long>();
lstLng.Add(1);
List<int> lstInt = lstLng.Cast<int>().ToList();
List<string> lstStr = lstLng.Select(lng => lng.ToString()).ToList();
```

[NOTE: If you aren't familiar with the `lng => lng.ToString()` part, it is called a *Lambda Expression*.]

`Cast<int>()`, unlike `OfType<int>()`, actually tries to convert each item to an int, skipping over any items that fail to convert. `Select()` just lets you build a whole new collection from your existing collection, using almost any kind of code you want.

I hope my real world examples help people to understand better the differences between .NET and Java when it comes to using functions with generic types.

Comment: Interesting read. I'm glad you found those LINQ methods helpful in your current situation.  I don't think there's anything special hidden behind them, though. I actually created my own OfType<X> extension method before I realized there was one built in already. The limitations of going from List<string> to a List<object> probably has more to do with type variance. I'm still using C# 3.5, but I think 4.0 introduced more support for this (like the 'in' and 'out' keywords for covariance and contravariance).

Comment: @slattery Actually, variance doesn't apply to classes, only interfaces and delegates. List does implement IEnumerable, which is covariant though, so you could do something like `IEnumerable<object> enumObj = new List<string>();` but you still couldn't then go `List<object> lstObj = (List<object>) enumObj;` without a cast exception because the concrete type is always going to be List<string>. Thus, when you do something like `List<object> lstObj = lstStr.OfType<object>().ToList();` a whole new List object is created and assigned.

Comment: @slattery Check out this article for more info on variance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx . It's interesting to note that IEnumberable<T> is variant and ICollection<T> is not. I think that is because some of the methods defined in ICollection<T> take T as a parameter. (Contravariance still messes with my mind...LOL) Thanks for your comments though. ;-)